# add to same SESSION array from different devices

Tags: php, html

I tried to store data in $_SESSION from Page A using mobile and then show the $_SESSION array in Page B using PC but that doesn't work, how to make that work?

Page A

```
<?php if (isset($_POST['r1'])){
    session_name('t1');
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['t1_r1'] = $_POST['r1'];}
?>
<form action="" method="POST" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="radio" name="r1" value="x" required>
    <label for="x">X</label>
    <input type="radio" name="r1" value="y">
    <label for="y">Y</label>
    <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>
```

Page B

```
<?php
    session_name('t1');
    session_start(); 
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_SESSION);
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

It worked when i tried from the same device 
(from PC to PC A sent to B) & 
(from Mobile to Mobile A sent to B)

Comment: Sessions are identified with some cookies, so you can't share them unless you are copying the cookies from the device A to the device B.

Comment: That's not really what sessions are for. You'll have to store the data somewhere else (database, file, etc).

Comment: Sessions are mapped to a PHPSESSID cookie stored on the client machine. To do this you need to assign the Session as normal, and map it to the user via a database or some other storage. Then when the user logs in from another client, check if there is an active session for that user then deliver them the PHPSESSID cookie in the event that they have one.

Comment: @thisistg how to copy the cookies from the device A to device B (i am new in coding a lot of concepts are not clear yet)

Comment: Don't copy session cookies around. As already pointed out, sessions are just the wrong tool here—they're only meant to overcome the limitation of HTTP being a stateless protocol. Use a proper database; it'll actually be easier to implement that anything you have in mind with sessions.